# Is Barcelona the most popular club in USA?

Tags: football

I saw an article: [The Ten Most Popular Club Jerseys In US in 2014/15](http://soccerlens.com/10-popular-club-jerseys-usa-20142015/165346/). I wonder if Barcelona is the the most popular club in USA? I would have thought it was Real Madrid?

Comment: Why do you think it should be Real?

Comment: The most popular club in every country should be a domestic one.

As far as the popularity contest goes on this level (10 most popular clubs) is just a momentarily view. AC Milan would have been among the most popular teams 10 years ago, now that part of football fans wouldn't be able to name 2 players from their current team.

This is just some uninteresting pissing contest between 10-20 clubs around the globe. And 15 or more from them being European.

Comment: This is an article about replica jersey sales.  It also does not say that the pictures are in any certain order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a couple comments about his (too much for a comment, though I'm not sure it's technically an answer either).

1) As Philip Kendall asks, I'm curious as to why you think it "should" be Real Madrid. Both teams do have fans all over the world, but I can't think of any rational as to why the US should fall on Madrid's side. In fact, many people in the Americas would be more likely to fall on Barca's side. During the rule of Francisco Franco, Real Madrid was seen as emblematic of the repressive dictatorship and FC Barcelona was viewed as representing the Republican resistance, so many latino-american countries (Mexico, central american and south american) rooted for Barcelona. The US was not a big soccer country at the time, so probably didn't pick sides, but there are plenty of immigrants from those areas in the US - that may be driving some of the preference (if, in fact, Barcelona is the preferred team - see points 2 and 3).

2) The article you link to is referencing one specific site, which sells jersey replicas. It's just one site, not a comprehensive reference.

3) If you look at the whole list, there are 3 different Real Madrid jerseys on the list (Away Black Champion's League, Home, and Away Pink), so it's possible more Real Madrid jerseys are sold overall, even if the Barca home one is the most popular individual jersey.

As a side note (unrelated to the original question, but interesting), it's important to understand what a "replica" jersey is. Official jerseys come in two styles - authentic and replica. Authentic means that it is identical to shirts that players wear on the field when they play - lighter weight, more ventilation, tighter fit, few other details. Replica means it is more for day-to-day use - looser, not ventilated, etc. This is different from the question of "real" vs. "fake". There can be real and fake versions of both. Fake (counterfeit) versions will have lower quality stitching and materials, may have design flaws (misaligned logos, misspellings, loose threads), and a host of other issues. Given that on the official nike site, the barca replica jerseys are $90 and on the site referenced, the barca replica jerseys are $17, I'm guessing the site referenced in the article is peddling counterfeit jerseys.